# Return just Keys from json HttpContext.Response in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a `HttpContext.Response` function which returns this json response:

```
{
    "[2-1] STORE[STORE_NBR]": 5026,
    "[2-1] STORE[STATE_PROV_CD]": "AR"        
}
```

Now, I just want the Keys to be returned and not the value as:

```
{
    [2-1] STORE[STORE_NBR],
    [2-1] STORE[STATE_PROV_CD]      
}
```

I tried commenting [1] and [2] but that result in an exception as value is expected. How can this outcome be achieved?

Comment: Without any value, it's not valid json. [json-objects](https://restfulapi.net/json-objects/). You could set the values to empty strings and then deserialize into a dictionary which you can read just the keys if you find that necessary. Otherwise, you could use the `StreamWriter` and write the keys to a text file and read them back with `StreamReader`

Comment: Also, your method doesn't return anything but a `Task`. So you may want to add to your post if you have another method which actually returns the json response. For the given method to return something, you'd use `Task<T>` where `T` is the return type to be wrapped in the `Task` being returned from the method.

Comment: @RyanWilson I think you're making a great point about the `HTTP` request in the post. From the look could be `async void` (if it doesn't need to be awaited), `async Task<T>` to await this conversion result or maybe it's fine as an awaitable `Task`. But I wanted to give you a heads up; My read is that this is a question about taking the Json response and parsing it out the the Keys and so I've submitted a proposed edit making it a Minimal Reproducible Example and removing that block entirely :)

Answer (score 1):

The Json response (as noted in a comment) can be easily deserialized to a Dictionary where both the `Key` and the `Value` of the `KeyValuePair` are strings. Here is how you could do that:

```
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json; // Can be installed as a NuGet package
```

then

```
var dictionary = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,string>>(source);
```

Once you have the dictionary object, you can use Linq to extract just the Keys that you want and turn them into a list.

```
List<string> keys =
    dictionary.Select(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Key).ToList();
```

where

```
const string source =
@"{
   ""[2 - 1] STORE[STORE_NBR]"": 5026,
   ""[2-1] STORE[STATE_PROV_CD]"": ""AR""        
  }";
```

These lines of code format the output you specified:

```
Console.WriteLine(
    "Here are the keys:");
Console.WriteLine(
    $"{{{Environment.NewLine}{string.Join("," + Environment.NewLine, keys)}{Environment.NewLine}}}");
```

[image: Here are the keys: [2 - 1] STORE[STORE_NBR],[2-1] STORE[STATE_PROV_CD]]

Comment: You wouldn't even need `Linq`, once it's a `Dictionary` you can just use the `.Keys` property of the `Dictionary`

Comment: @RyanWilson I'm glad you said that. I always see the metadata for the Dictionary.Keys collection which is defined as `public Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection Keys` and think _"but I just want an array of strings"_. So now I agree and that's just one of those silly gaps in my knowledge after what 45 years of doing this stuff. An array of strings it is. Thank you.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for providing a solution to the OP's question. I forget things all the time. You should see my browser bookmarks, lol. :P

Comment: And doesn't anyone _else_ want to weigh in about it really being more of an `IEnumerable<TKey>`? You disappoint me lol.